# Azure Storage - Uploading .zip file with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure DevOps build pipeline that includes a PowerShell task. That task uploads a file to Azure Storage. At this time, I've created the following script:

**PowerShell Script**

```
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ./test
New-Item -Path ./test -Name "file.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "hello world"

Compress-Archive -Path ./test/* -DestinationPath ./test.zip

$azureStorageKey = "<MyAccessKey>"
$storage_context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "mystorageaccount" -StorageAccountKey "$azureStorageKey"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $storage_context -Container "mycontainer" -File "./test.zip" -Blob "temp/test.zip" -Force
```

This script successfully runs on my local machine and in Azure DevOps. While I can *see* the `test.zip` file in my Azure Storage account, it seems corrupted.

From the Azure Portal, I choose "Download" from the `test.zip` file blob context menu. The `test.zip` file gets downloaded to my machine. I then try to unzip the archive file by selecting "Expand All..." from the File Explorer on Windows. When I do that, I receive an error that says:

```
Windows cannot open the folder.

The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'C:\Users\me\Downloads\test.zip' is invalid.
```

Why does this archive file seem corrupt? It's fine on my local machine. But, when I download it from the Azure Portal, I can't extract the contents of the archive. What am I missing? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you checked the validness of test.zip before uploading it?

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft - Yes. The test.zip is valid before it's uploaded.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems caused by blob storage itself, I can reproduce your issue on my side.

Even if upload and download the compressed file(have test `.zip`and `.rar` type) manually in the portal(also test with `v1` and`v2` tier of storage account), it also gives the error.

You could open a issue in the github, besides, if it is possible, you could use [file storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share) to do that, [Managing Azure file shares with Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-powershell), it will work fine.

**Update**:

It may be a bug of azure portal, I download the compressed file in the storage explorer and upzip it,  it works fine. So you could try to use [storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to do it.